Saslauthd service not starting after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
I stuck with not starting saslauthd service after upgrade Ubuntu to 24.04 (it runs along with Virutalmin). So i can't authenticate to smtp (cant send mails, but still can recieve) due to error:
454 4.7.0 Temporary authetnitaction failure: generic failiure
I was trying to run saslauthd service by (systemctl status saslauthd shows service as:  inactive (dead)):
systemctl start saslauthd
ends with timed out:
Job for saslauthd.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status saslauthd.service" and "journalctl -xeu saslauthd.service" for details.

during the start process - its create some files in /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd but after it ends with time out - directory its again empty.
I managed to run saslauthd by command bellow:
/usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5
and authorization started to work
Also after creating symlink:
ln -s /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd /var/run
I can start saslauthd by systemctl start saslauthd and it works.

tested with command bellow (also desktop client works):

nc localhost 25
220 ################ ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
######
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
######
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful

Envoirnment:
postfix 3.8.6
saslauthd 2.1.28
Ubuntu 24.04

Postfix 3.8.6 smtp config
/etc/postfix/master.cf:
smtp   inet    n   -   y   -   -   smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtps  inet    n   -   y   -   -   smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
saslauthd 2.1.28 config
/etc/default/saslauthd (remove commented lines)
START=yes

DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"

NAME="saslauthd"

MECHANISMS="pam"

OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"

THREADS=5

OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
PARAMS="-m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"


I can't vouch for Virtulmin as I don't use it but what I did notice is that Ubuntu 24.04 uses a correct systemd file for saslauthd compared to 22.04 which used the init file loaded via systemd.
To get it working with Postfix 3.8 in a chroot on Ubuntu 24.04 this is what I did.  This might not be what Virtulmin does or expects but it might help you figure it out.
Create /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN

Run...
sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
sudo chmod 710 /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
sudo chown :sasl /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
adduser postfix sasl

Create /etc/default/saslauthd-postfix
NAME="saslauthd-postf"
MECHANISMS="pam"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"

Create /etc/systemd/system/saslauthd-postfix.service
[Unit]
Description=SASL Authentication Daemon for Postfix
Documentation=man:saslauthd(8)

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/saslauthd-postfix
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saslauthd -a $MECHANISMS $MECH_OPTIONS $OPTIONS -n $THREADS
RuntimeDirectory=saslauthd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Run..
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable saslauthd-postfix.service
sudo systemctl start saslauthd-postfix.service

Obviously you need the relevant postfix configuration in main.cf or master.cf so thats is assumed here - likewise the relevant packages installed.

If it doesn't work for you, try adding -r to the OPTIONS in /etc/default/saslauthd-postfix so it reads OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd" > -r' Combine the realm with the login (with an '@' sign in between). e.g. login: "foo" realm: "bar" will get passed as login: "foo@bar". Note that the realm will still be passed, which may lead to unexpected behavior.

In my case it was just the pid file location that needed to be changed.
The error I was getting:
Dec 16 22:47:29 out01 systemd[1]: Starting saslauthd.service - SASL Authentication Daemon...
Dec 16 22:47:29 out01 saslauthd[2916]:                 : master pid is: 2916
Dec 16 22:47:29 out01 systemd[1]: saslauthd.service: Can't open PID file /run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Dec 16 22:47:29 out01 saslauthd[2916]:                 : listening on socket: /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux
Dec 16 22:48:59 out01 systemd[1]: saslauthd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Dec 16 22:48:59 out01 systemd[1]: saslauthd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 16 22:48:59 out01 systemd[1]: Failed to start saslauthd.service - SASL Authentication Daemon.
Dec 16 22:52:13 out01 systemd[1]: saslauthd.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.

The solution:
edit saslauthd.service and set the correct path to the pid file in jailed postfix enviromend.
systemctl edit saslauthd.service

In my case it looks like this:
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/saslauthd.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the contents of the drop-in file

[Service]
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid

### Edits below this comment will be discarded


### /usr/lib/systemd/system/saslauthd.service
# [Unit]
# Description=SASL Authentication Daemon
# Documentation=man:saslauthd(8)
# 
# [Service]
# Type=forking
# PIDFile=/var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid
# EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/saslauthd
# ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saslauthd -a $MECHANISMS $MECH_OPTIONS $OPTIONS -n $THREADS
# RuntimeDirectory=saslauthd
# 
# [Install]
# WantedBy=multi-user.target

